# Two Navigation in two slider

Tags: swiper.js

Hello I am using thumb slider. Both the gallery-top slider has navigation. There is also a gallery-thumb slider navigation. I cannot run them synchronously. Because when I add navigation in the gallery-thumb slider, the swiper-button-next and swiper-button-prev classes become disable. How can I solve this problem

-->> HTML CODE

```
<div class="swiper-container news-detail-slider gallery-top" >
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <picture>
                <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none"><![endif]-->
                <source srcset="temp/753x510.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                <img src="temp/.jpg" data-loadmode="0" alt=""><!-- mobile -->
                </picture>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <picture>
                <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none"><![endif]-->
                <source srcset="temp/753x510.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                <img src="temp/.jpg" data-loadmode="0" alt=""><!-- mobile -->
                </picture>
            </a>
        </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <picture>
                <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none"><![endif]-->
                <source srcset="temp/753x510.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                <img src="temp/.jpg" data-loadmode="0" alt=""><!-- mobile -->
                </picture>
            </a>
        </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <picture>
                <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none"><![endif]-->
                <source srcset="temp/753x510.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                <img src="temp/.jpg" data-loadmode="0" alt=""><!-- mobile -->
                </picture>
            </a>
        </div>
               <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <picture>
                <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none"><![endif]-->
                <source srcset="temp/753x510.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                <img src="temp/.jpg" data-loadmode="0" alt=""><!-- mobile -->
                </picture>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs"> 
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span>1</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span>2</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span>3</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span>4</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span>5</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
```

JS CODE -->

```
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 5,
      freeMode: true,
      watchSlidesVisibility: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.gallery-thumbs .swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.gallery-thumbs .swiper-button-prev', 
    },
    });

   var galleryTop = new Swiper('.news-detail-slider', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.news-detail-slider .swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.news-detail-slider .swiper-button-prev', 
    },
    autoplay:{
        delay: 4000,
        disableOnInteraction: !1
    },
    effect: "flipEffect",
    slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
    speed: 800,
    flipEffect: {
        rotate: 0,
        stretch: -10,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 3,
        slideShadows: !1
    },
    spaceBetween: 0,
    thumbs: {
        swiper: galleryThumbs
    }
});
```

https://i.hizliresim.com/FqQ2ef.jpg

Comment: Sory , True link is ------------>> https://i.hizliresim.com/ALSVOg.png

Comment: You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Non-progamming-hint: Ask your designer/project-manager/stake-holder, if two sliders on one webpage are really necessary. Please proof, if their effect on the overall user experience is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out.

You need to add .swiper-container to all the new Swiper classes to in your case

`var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.swiper-container.gallery-thumbs', {`

`var galleryTop = new Swiper('.swiper-container.news-detail-slider', {`

Then magically swiper knows there are multiples on the page.

Also make sure that the structure of your markup is like the demo

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container swiper-one">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

See that the swiper-wrapper is inside the container, but the navigation elements are outside the wrapper